# Comparar dos arrays elemento a elemento

Tags: python, numpy

Hola estoy aprendiendo Python y estoy atascado en un problema.
Debo comparar los elementos de los dos arrays y obtener uno nuevo con los valores mayores de cada par.

```
array1 = np.array([5, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 7])
array2 = np.array([1, 5, 9, 3, 5, 1, 2])

array([5, 6, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7])
```

He probado hacerlo elemento por elemento, de esta forma:

```
def valor_maximo(x, y):
  for i, j in zip(x, y):
    if i >= j:
      return i
    else:
      return j
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado esperado, solo compara el primer par. Podrian decirme que estoy haciendo mal y darme algunos consejos de como resolverlo, debo hacerlo en forma de función.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma aún más corta de obtener la lista es evaluando

```
[max(x) for x in zip(array1, array2)]
```

La función `zip` crea una nueva lista (un iterador en realidad) de tuplas, donde el primer elemento viene de `array1` y el segundo de `array2`:

```
(5, 1) (6, 5) (5, 9) (2, 3) (1, 5) (4, 1) (7, 2)
```

El `for` recorre esta lista de tuplas, y la función `max` evalua cada tupla, retornado el máximo valor de cada par.

Finalmente, encerramos todo entre "[]" y tenemos la lista deseada

Asi queda:

```
array1 = [5, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 7]
array2 = [1, 5, 9, 3, 5, 1, 2]
maximo = [max(x) for x in zip(array1, array2)]
print(maximo)
```

produce:

```
[5, 6, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás esto te sirva:

```
array1 = [5, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 7]
array2 = [1, 5, 9, 3, 5, 1, 2]
def valor_maximo(x, y):
   return [max(x[i],y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]

print(valor_maximo(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Publica también el resultado de la ejecución, para que se vea que si funciona la solución.